# Create a button that would redirect the user to WiFi settings in Kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I'm making an app for Android and iOS devices, and I need to create a method that would open the Android or iOS wifi settings that I could call in on_release(). The button looks this way:

```
MDFillRoundFlatButton:
    text: "Settings"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    on_release: app.wifisettings()
    md_bg_color: (33/255, 150/255, 243/255)
    text_color: 'FFFFFF'
    size_hint_x: 0.6
    size_hint_y: 0.05
```